# SQL, usar una columna con el mismo nombre, Access

Tags: mysql, sql

Soy un estudiante y en mi curso me pidieron que mostrara en una consulta de SQL los campos que no aparecen en una tabla.

```
SELECT *
       FROM Productos LEFT OUTER JOIN Ventas ON Productos.ID_Prod=Ventas.ID_Prod
       where (Esta es la parte donde no se que hacer)
```

Me disculpo por mi pobre código pero es lo que hay en mi curso. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Mi duda es como hago que SQL entienda que el `ID_Prod` que quiero que tome es el que se encuentra en la tabla `Ventas`

Comment: Bienvenido, serías tan amable de explicar mejor tu duda, no entiendo a que te refieres con los campos que no aparecen en la la tabla

Comment: Si gustas, puedo pasarte el archivo o fotos de mis tablas. 

Lo que quiero saber es como hago para que SQL entienda que quiero especificar que debe tomar el ID_Prod que pertenecer a Ventas

Comment: Pudieras partir colocando la estructura de las tablas asociadas, ya que no queda del todo clara tu pregunta, considera leer [ask]

Comment: O usas un  alias de tabla (recomendable) o referencias a la columna junto con el nombre de tabla, por ejemplo `Ventas.Id_Prod`

Answer (score 2):

Con respecto a tu duda de como haces que SQL entienda que el ID_prod hace referencia a la tabla ventas, lo entiende cuando le decis `JOIN Ventas ON Productos.ID_Prod=Ventas.ID_Prod`, con esa instrucción le estas diciendo unime las dos tablas con esas claves. O sea que está bien lo que tenes salvo el `where` que no hace falta. El `outer` si querers no lo escribis.
O sea que Si haces esta consulta:

```
SELECT *
FROM Productos JOIN Ventas ON Productos.ID_Prod=Ventas.ID_Prod
```

te va a devolver todos los `productos` que estén en la tabla `ventas`, o sea todos aquellos productos que se hayan vendido.
Ahora qué pasa con aquellos `productos` que no se vendieron al menos una vez? No los va a mostrar esta consulta, entonces para eso existe el `join` por derecha o izquierda. Entonces haciéndole un `left join`, así:

```
SELECT *
FROM Productos LEFT JOIN Ventas ON Productos.ID_Prod=Ventas.ID_Prod
```

como `Productos` se encuentra a la **izquierda**, le estás diciendo que te muestre todos los productos por mas que no hayan registrado alguna venta. Por lo tanto te va a devolver todos los productos, y los que no hayan registrado alguna venta aparecerán pero el resto de los campos de ese registro serán `null`